# Jmeter how I can extract token only 1 time and use it for do x request to my api

Tags: multithreading, testing, jmeter, token, author

I try to do a first http call to take a token only one time and then use it for do my others http calls. I put my config:

Thread group:
1- 20 number threads whith one call for thread

Http requests:
1- Extract token
This call extract a token and put it value in variable call it (author)
2-Call first api with token
3- Call second api with token

My problem is why I can't request 20 times a token becouse server collapse. I need only do a 1 token call and then use it the token for other 40 http requests.

Sorry I don't have a good english.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test) to get the token with 1 user
2. Save to token into a property using [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty)
3. Read the property in 2nd Thread Group using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P)

Comment: I use property like you explain but I can't get value for setted on header